# How to get Database-table entries where a certain column is not linked to a certain value by another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following tables: Students, Classes, link_student_class. Where Students contains the information about the registered students and classes contains the information about the classes. As every student can attend multiple classes and every class can be attended by multiple students, I added a linking-table, for the mapping between students and classes.

Linking-Table

```
id | student_id | class_id
1    1            1
2    1            2
3    2            1
4    3            3
```

In this table both student_id as well as class_id will appear multiple times!
What I am looking for, is a SQL-Query that returns the information about all students (like in 'SELECT * FROM students') that are not attending a certain class (given by its id).

I tried the following SQL-query

```
SELECT * FROM `students` 
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT * FROM link_student_class
    WHERE class_id = $class_id
    )
link_student_class ON link_student_class.student_id = students.student_id
```

Where $class_id is the id of the class which students i want to exclude.

In the returned object the students i want to include and those i want to exclude are different in the value of the column 'class_id'.
Those to be included have the value 'NULL' whereas those I want to exclude have a numerical value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check for NULL link_student_class.student_id

```
SELECT * 
FROM `students` 
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT * 
    FROM link_student_class
    WHERE class_id = $class_id
) link_student_class ON link_student_class.student_id = students.student_id
where link_student_class.student_id  is null
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I already tried where link_student_class.student_id  = NULL, but that didn't work. However, as far as I can see, your solution seems to work pretty well.

Comment: in sql  you can't use  id = null  but you must use id IS null

Answer (score 1):

`NOT EXISTS` comes to mind:

```
select s.*
from students s
where not exists (select 1
                  from link_student_class lsc
                  where lsc.student_id = s.student_id and
                        lsc.class_id = ?
                 );
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the parameter that provides the class.

Answer (score 0):

Or also a NOT IN predicate:

```
WITH
stud_class(id,stud_id,class_id) AS (
          SELECT 1,   1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 3,   2,1
UNION ALL SELECT 4,   3,3
)
,
stud(stud_id,fname,lname) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Arthur','Dent'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Ford','Prefect'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Tricia','McMillan'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'Zaphod','Beeblebrox'
)
SELECT 
  s.*
FROM stud s
WHERE stud_id NOT IN (
  SELECT
    stud_id
  FROM stud_class
  WHERE class_id= 2
);
-- out  stud_id | fname  |   lname    
-- out ---------+--------+------------
-- out        3 | Tricia | McMillan
-- out        4 | Zaphod | Beeblebrox
-- out        2 | Ford   | Prefect
-- out (3 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (3 rows): 9.516 ms. All rows formatted: 9.550 ms
```